# Live filter multiple taxonomy queries

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, filtering

I am creating a front end filter that contains checkboxes the visittors can click to sort posts based on taxonomies. The posts they can filter is a custom post type with 3 taxonomies attached to it.

This is a custom ajax live filter, so that whenever someone clicks a checkbox, the result is returned, no page load and no submit buttons.

The front end works fine, the information that is sent to the endpoint is fine, and if I narrow the query down to only one taxonomy everything works as expected, regardless of the taxonomy i narrow the filter down to. But with multiple taxonomies in the query I run in to problems. This is the first time I am creating something like this, so I hope it's just a minor thing that I haven't thought of, but no matter what I try, the taxonomy filter only filters by the first taxonomy that has a term that is checked.

**An example:**

*Tax 1
Tax 2
Tax 3*

If the first checkbox that is clicked belongs to *Tax 1*, then it will only filter within *Tax 1*. If I try to click on a checkbox that belongs to *Tax 2* or *Tax 3*, it disregards those terms/tax entirely, and still only filters by the first taxonomy.

I know I am doing something wrong in the query, so I am really hoping someone here on SO can give me some guidence on what I am supposed to do to get this working.

**Here is the endpoint (*query*):**

```
function myFilter ($data) {

    $checkFylker          = $data['checkFylker'];
    $checkUtstyr          = $data['checkUtstyr'];
    $checkFors            = $data['checkFors'];
    $checkType            = $data['checkType'];


    //return $results;


  //Main $args
  $args = array(
      'post_type'     => 'ml_opp', // Query only "ml_opp" custom posts
      'post_status'   => 'publish', // Query only posts with "publish" status
      'orderby'       => 'date', // Sort posts by date
      'order'         => 'ASC' // ASC
    );



    $args['tax_query'] = array( 'relation'=>'AND' ); // AND means that all conditions of meta_query should be true

    // for taxonomies / utstyr
    if( isset( $checkUtstyr ) )
      $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        array(
          'taxonomy'  => 'ml_utstyr',
          'field'     => 'id',
          'terms'     => $checkUtstyr
        )
      );

    //for taxonomies / forsendelse
    if( isset( $checkFors ) )
      $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        array(
          'taxonomy'  => 'ml_forsendelse',
          'field'     => 'id',
          'terms'     => $checkFors
        )
      );

    // for taxonomies / fylker
    if( isset( $checkFylker ) )
      $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
          'taxonomy'  => 'ml_fylk',
          'field'     => 'id',
          'terms'     => $checkFylker
        )
      );

    // for taxonomies / type
    if( isset( $checkType ) )
      $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
          'taxonomy'  => 'ml_typ',
          'field'     => 'id',
          'terms'     => $checkType
        )
      );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
      while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
        echo '<h2>' . $query->post->post_title . '</h2>';
      endwhile;
      wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
      echo 'No posts found';
    endif;

    die();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your all `isset` conditions are wrongly interpreted to match the `tax_query`. See updated below code snippet and compare with yours to find the difference.

```
function myFilter ($data) {

    $checkFylker          = $data['checkFylker'];
    $checkUtstyr          = $data['checkUtstyr'];
    $checkFors            = $data['checkFors'];
    $checkType            = $data['checkType'];


    //return $results;


  //Main $args
  $args = array(
      'post_type'     => 'ml_opp', // Query only "ml_opp" custom posts
      'post_status'   => 'publish', // Query only posts with "publish" status
      'orderby'       => 'date', // Sort posts by date
      'order'         => 'ASC' // ASC
    );

    $args['tax_query'] = array( 'relation'=>'AND' ); // AND means that all conditions of meta_query should be true

    // for taxonomies / utstyr
    if( isset( $checkUtstyr ) )
      $args['tax_query'][] = array(
          'taxonomy'  => 'ml_utstyr',
          'field'     => 'id',
          'terms'     => $checkUtstyr
      );

    //for taxonomies / forsendelse
    if( isset( $checkFors ) )
      $args['tax_query'][] = array(
          'taxonomy'  => 'ml_forsendelse',
          'field'     => 'id',
          'terms'     => $checkFors
      );

    // for taxonomies / fylker
    if( isset( $checkFylker ) )
      $args['tax_query'][] = array(
          'taxonomy'  => 'ml_fylk',
          'field'     => 'id',
          'terms'     => $checkFylker
      );

    // for taxonomies / type
    if( isset( $checkType ) )
      $args['tax_query'][] = array(
          'taxonomy'  => 'ml_typ',
          'field'     => 'id',
          'terms'     => $checkType
     );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
      while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
        echo '<h2>' . $query->post->post_title . '</h2>';
      endwhile;
      wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
      echo 'No posts found';
    endif;
    die();
  }
```